# react-native-gesture-handler can not be installed and shows compilation error

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-vector-icons

I initially tried using the react-native-elements for icons and other components. I followed the documentation to set things up but the icons were visible as a cross in a rectangle. During this I linked the vector icons by running "react-native link react-native-vector-icons" and also had added the following in setting.gradle in the android folder of the project:

```
rootProject.name = 'Vida'

apply from: '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/gradle.groovy'
includeUnimodulesProjects()

apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-
```

android/native_modules.gradle");
applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)

```
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new 
File(rootProject.projectDir, 
 '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
```

Also the mainApplication.java file needed changes so I changed it to following:

```
@Override
  protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
  packages.add(new ModuleRegistryAdapter(mModuleRegistryProvider));
  package.add(new RNGestureHandlerPackage()); // THis is the change I made for handling gestures.
    

   return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
  new MainReactPackage(),
  new VectorIconsPackage() // THis is the change for vector Icons
);
}
```

I also added the

```
implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
```

to build.gradle file.

After I restarted the app by first "react-native start" and "react-native run-android" and I came across "null is not an object ( evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.default.Direction')" in my android emulator after which I tried searching online for solution and some saidn unistalling and reinstalling react-native-gesture-handlers will solve it so I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the gesture handler and tried restarting the meteor server and run "react-native run-android". But rather, I came across an error saying:

```
C:\Vida\VidaApp@20\VidaArchive\android\app\src\main\java\blah\com\MainActivity.java:8: 
com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react does not exist
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;
                                     ^
C:\Vida\VidaApp@20\VidaArchive\android\app\src\main\java\blah\com\MainActivity.java:37:
find symbol 
return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
                       ^
symbol: class RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option  output. Run 
with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
eact does not exist
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;;
                                     ^                               ivity.java:37:
C:\Vida\VidaApp@20\VidaArchive\android\app\src\main\java\blah\com\MainActivity.java:37: error: cannot 
find symbol                                 his);
    return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
                       ^
symbol: class RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
                                                                     -debug option 
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more 
log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 38s
                                                                     t-native-commu
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:635:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:653:15)                            tive-community
at runOnAllDevices (C:\Vida\VidaApp@20\VidaArchive\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform- 
android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAly\cli-platformlDevices.js:94:39)
at buildAndRun (C:\Vida\VidaApp@20\VidaArchive\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform- 
android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:17dules\react-na9:41)
at C:\Vida\VidaApp@20\VidaArchive\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform- 
android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:133:12
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)  
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Vida\VidaApp@20\VidaArchive\node_modules\react- 
native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:182:9)
```

Also while I tried uninstalling gesture handler, visual studio crashed out and i had to open again and after I launched Vscode I reinstalled gesture-handlers, it showed the following error:

```
$ ...include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
bash: ...include: command not found

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: file-uri-to-path@1.0.0 (node_modules\file-uri-to- 
path):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 
'C:\Vida\VidaApp@20\VidaArchive\node_modules\file-uri-to-path' -> 
'C:\Vida\VidaApp@20\VidaArchive\node_modules\.file-uri-to-path.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: nan@2.14.2 (node_modules\nan):
 npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 
'C:\Vida\VidaApp@20\VidaArchive\node_modules\nan' 
-> 'C:\Vida\VidaApp@20\VidaArchive\node_modules\.nan.DELETE'

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Vida\VidaApp@20\VidaArchive\node_modules\@egjs\hammerjs
npm ERR! dest C:\Vida\VidaApp@20\VidaArchive\node_modules\@egjs\.hammerjs.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 
'C:\Vida\VidaApp@20\VidaArchive\node_modules\@egjs\hammerjs' -> 
'C:\Vida\VidaApp@20\VidaArchive\node_modules\@egjs\.hammerjs.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Shiri\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-31T07_52_44_306Z-debug.log
```

Currently my package.json file is as below:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.8.1",
    "@redux-offline/redux-offline": "^2.6.0-expo.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "expo": "~37.0.3",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "^1.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.2.3",
    "expo-updates": "~0.2.0",
    "pusher-js": "^7.0.0",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "~0.61.5",
    "react-native-agora": "^2.9.1-alpha.7",
    "react-native-banner-carousel": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-country-list": "^1.0.10",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.0.0-alpha.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "^0.16.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-rename": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.7.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.0",
    "react-native-svg": "11.0.1",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.9.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.3.9",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.5.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "babel-jest": "~25.2.6",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0",
    "jest": "~25.2.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "~16.9.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "name": "VidaArchive",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

I need this issue to be fixed early because I need to show my work to my seniors. Also I am new to react-native environment, Hence, my concerns are:

1. How to set up and use react-native vector icons for android (alongwith third party libraries)?
2. What is this issue, RNGestureHandler?
3. It says Package react-native-gesture-handler has been ignored because it contains invalid
   Reason: Cannot find module 'react-native-gesture-handler\package.json'. What is this and what is causing it so and how can I fix this?